# dark mode interfering with background color

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, android-dark-theme

I'm trying to apply background colors to my app and for some reason I can't get the right colors

for example:

```
<View style={{backgroundColor:'yellow'}}></View>
```

but I'm getting

[image] [image]

the first one in system dark mode and second one in light mode ( [settings](https://i.ibb.co/Wsnfxf0/image.png) & [phone model](https://amzn.to/3jbe6Ot) )

so how do I get consistent colors in any mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if I understand you right.
But I assume you don't want your App to be able to force dark mode right?
Some of our users with the same Redmi Phone you mentioned also had the problem with forced dark mode which made the appearance pretty ugly.

If so, add the item 'forceDarkAllowed' set to false inside your */android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml*

```
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_screen_bitmap</item>
    <item name="android:forceDarkAllowed">false</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not hardcode the color like this. try to use color dynamically based on the light or dark theme.

Use the package like this :

[react-native-appearance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-appearance)

Comment: I'm trying to give it fixed look despite any system theme, also do you have a solution that doesn't require a third party package?

Comment: Yes, This is the best tutorial on this : 
https://buttercms.com/blog/implement-dark-mode-react-native 5 ways to do it!